# fallback for limitting web application access to certain ip addresses

Tags: security, web-applications

We develop a web application.
There is a user login and a user area for the customers of a certain company.
And there is an agent/office login and area for some employees of the company who manage user account handling and so on.

The office agent has to login with his username and password.

But additionally, for security reasons, we will limit the agent/office login and area for specific IP addresses (as seen in other applications).

But we would like to have a "fallback" for certain situations where, for example, a web developer of the application needs access to the office area and has not one of the special IP addresses.

Until now we had not many ideas.

We thought of providing access when there is a very special user-agent string with a hash value.

Has anybody implemented such security mechanisms and can inform me about it?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Can you require web developers to use VPN to access the system? That is probably the most secure solution you'll find.

Comment: Hello Neil! When the responsible developer is at work or at home or can use his laptop, then he can use the VPN. But when there is an occasion, that he is out of office and not at home and cannot use his laptop a fallback would be helpful.